# Understanding object initializer notation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In the [**sec 11.1.5**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) of ECMA-262 we have the object declaration notation:

```
ObjectLiteral :
    { }
    { PropertyNameAndValueList }
    { PropertyNameAndValueList , }
PropertyNameAndValueList :
    PropertyAssignment
    PropertyNameAndValueList , PropertyAssignment
PropertyAssignment :
    PropertyName : AssignmentExpression
    get PropertyName ( ) { FunctionBody }
    set PropertyName ( PropertySetParameterList ) { FunctionBody }
PropertyName :
    IdentifierName
    StringLiteral
    NumericLiteral
PropertySetParameterList :
    Identifier
```

Well, consider the following `ObjectLiteral`: `{prop: 'prop'}`. Thus we have literal of the form `{PropertyName: AssignmentExpression}`. Now clearly that `'prop'` is `AssignmentExpression`. By defenition from [**sec 11.13**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13), `AssignmentExpression` is

```
AssignmentExpression :
    ConditionalExpression 
    LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression 
    LeftHandSideExpression AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression
```

**Question:**

Why `'prop'` is `AssignmentExpression`? There is no `AssignmentOperator` or `=` and `'prop'` is no `ConditionalExpression` certanly.

Comment: Surely `{prop: 'prop'}` is a `PropertyNameAndValueList`?

Comment: @lonesomeday I'm confused, can you explain how `'prop'` is evaluated in my `ObjectLiteral`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *AssignmentExpression* means pretty much any expression in the language, other than ones that use the comma operator/punctuator.

Basically, the production rules have operator precedence and associativity baked in.

```
 AssignmentExpression 
 => ConditionalExpression                          (11.13)
  => LogicalORExpression                           (11.12)
   => LogicalANDExpression                         (11.11)
    => BitwiseORExpression                         (11.10)
     => BitwiseXORExpression                       (11.10)
      => BitwiseANDExpression                      (11.10)
       => EqualityExpression                       (11.10)
        => RelationalExpression                    (11.9)
         => ShiftExpression                        (11.8)
          => AdditiveExpression                    (11.7)
           => MultiplicativeExpression             (11.6)
            => UnaryExpression                     (11.5)
             => PostfixExpression                  (11.4)
              => LeftHandSideExpression            (11.3)
               => NewExpression                    (11.2)
                => MemberExpression                (11.2)
                 => PrimaryExpression              (11.2)
                  => Literal                       (11.1)
                   => StringLiteral                (7.8)
                    => ' SingleStringChars(opt) '  (7.8.4)
```

Note how the deeper we go, the higher the precedence.  You probably already knew that `*` has higher precedence than `+` or `-`, for example.  One very common way of specifying precedence in a grammar is to have a production rule for each tier of operators, and specifically say (for example) that an "additive expression" is one or more "multiplicative expressions" separated by `+` or `-`.  Given such a rule, the parser would have to handle multiplicative subexpressions before it could even attempt to produce an addition or subtraction expression.

Comment: In the 11.1.5 said that _The values need not be literals; they are evaluated each time the object initialiser is evaluated._ But as i understood from your post `AssignmentExpression` can be a `Literal`

Comment: Right.  Can be, but doesn't have to be.

Comment: Awesome explanation! I'm understand. Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

> `'prop'` is no `ConditionalExpression` certainly.

Yes it is. The term conditional doesn't mean that it necessarily contains a conditional, but that it is at the grammatical level of expressions that *are allowed to contain* conditionals - to achieve the [operator associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) ordering.

Here's a break down:

```
ConditionalExpression: LogicalORExpression (§11.12)
LogicalORExpression: LogicalANDExpression (§11.11)
LogicalANDExpression: BitwiseORExpression (§11.11)
BitwiseORExpression: BitwiseXORExpression (§11.10)
BitwiseXORExpression: BitwiseANDExpression (§11.10)
BitwiseANDExpression: EqualityExpression (§11.10)
EqualityExpression: RelationalExpression (§11.9)
RelationalExpression: ShiftExpression (§11.8)
ShiftExpression: AdditiveExpression (§11.7)
AdditiveExpression: MultiplicativeExpression (§11.6)
MultiplicativeExpression: UnaryExpression (§11.5)
UnaryExpression: PostfixExpression (§11.4)
PostfixExpression: LeftHandSideExpression (§11.3)
LeftHandSideExpression: NewExpression (§11.2)
NewExpression: MemberExpression (§11.2)
MemberExpression: PrimaryExpression (§11.2)
PrimaryExpression: Literal (§11.1)
Literal: StringLiteral (§7.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an `AssignmentExpression` because you're allowed to write:

```
{ prop: a = 'prop' }
```

or:

```
{ prop: a == 3 ? 'prop1' : 'prop2' }
```